# Is measurement of $M\otimes I$ equivalent to measurement of $M$ on first subsystem?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, measurement, linear-algebra

Let $\rho$ be a state in $H_A\otimes H_B$ and $\rho_A$ its reduced state on $H_A$ (obtained by tracing out $H_B$).

Is the probability distribution corresponding to the observable $M\otimes I$ on $\rho$ exactly the same as the probability distribution corresponding to the observable $M$ on $\rho_A$? In other words, is the probability of observing a given eigenvalue of $M$ the same in both cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the probability distributions are the same.

Physically, we can draw this conclusion from the fact that quantum operations - of which partial trace and measurement$^1$ are examples - on disjoint subsystems commute, which is another way of saying that they are causally independent.

Mathematically, we can show the equality of the two distributions as follows. If $M$ has eigendecomposition $M=\sum_i\lambda_i P_i$ then $M\otimes I_B=\sum_i\lambda_i P_i\otimes I_B$. The probability $p(\lambda_i|M\otimes I,\rho)$ that the measurement of $M\otimes I$ on state $\rho$ yields the outcome $\lambda_i$ is

$$
\begin{align}
p(\lambda_i|M\otimes I,\rho) &= \mathrm{tr}(P_i\otimes I_B\rho)\tag1\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{tr}_B(P_i\otimes I_B\rho))\tag2\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(P_i\mathrm{tr}_B(I_A\otimes I_B\rho))\tag3\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(P_i\mathrm{tr}_B\rho)\tag4\\
&=\mathrm{tr}(P_i\rho_A)\tag5\\
&=p(\lambda_i|M,\rho_A)\tag6
\end{align}
$$

which is the probability that the measurement of $M$ on $\rho_A$ yields the outcome $\lambda_i$. The equality $(1)$ is the Born rule, the equality $(2)$ is an easily-checked property of the trace which says that tracing over both subsystems $A$ and $B$ is equivalent to tracing over $B$ followed by tracing over $A$, equality $(3)$ is a defining property of the partial trace which says that operators on subsystems not being traced out may be pulled out of the partial trace, equality $(4)$ is obvious, equality $(5)$ is the definition of $\rho_A$ and $(6)$ is another use of the Born rule. The same argument, essentially unchanged, applies to measurements described by a POVM.

---

<sup>$^1$ Strictly speaking, measurement is described by a *collection* of non-trace-preserving quantum operations.</sup>